# Can't install Steam through AppCenter

Tags: appcenter

I had no trouble installing steam through the terminal using `sudo apt install steam`, however any attempt at installing Steam through the AppCenter would do nothing.

I am able to install other applications through the AppCenter without problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. When I click "install", I briefly get a "waiting in queue" message, which then disappears. I can install through the command line. The command line installation requires that the user accept a license agreement - I wonder whether this trips up AppCenter.

Comment: Bugreport - https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1622229